# Detect Duplicate title - Wordpress RPC

Tags: php, wordpress

I am posting to wordpress using below code

```
   <?php
            require("class-IXR.php");  
            $client = new IXR_Client('http://domain.com/xmlrpc.php');

            $USER = 'user';
            $PASS = 'pass';

            $content['title'] = 'Test title';
            $content['categories'] = array("games");
            $content['description'] = '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>';
            $content['custom_fields'] = array( array('key' => 'my_custom_fied','value'=>'yes') );
            $content['mt_keywords'] = array('foo','bar');

            if (!$client->query('metaWeblog.newPost','', $USER,$PASS, $content, true))
            {
                die( 'Error while creating a new post' . $client->getErrorCode() ." : ". $client->getErrorMessage());  
            }
            $ID =  $client->getResponse();

            if($ID)
            {
                echo 'Post published with ID:#'.$ID;
            }

    ?>
```

How can i avoid posting duplicate title.For example if i already have post with title `Test it` . When i try to post another post with title `Test it` it should not post.

P.s : I have 1000's of post in my blog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (is_null(get_page_by_title( $content['title'], OBJECT, 'post'))) {

// Do your stuff in this case (no post with the same title)

}

else {

// Do not create post

}
```

Comment: This will work if you are inside WordPress, but not on the API.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check for a duplicate WordPress post using the WordPress XML-RPC API, you are going to need to use `wp.getPosts` to get a list of all the WordPress posts that have been made, and then loop through all the posts to ensure that there is no duplicate.

As seen in https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Posts, you will need to retrieve a list of all the blog posts first, then loop through all of them to find out if post_title or post_name is already set.

```
$result = $client->query('wp.getPosts','', $USER, $PASS)
if (!$result) {
    die( 'Error while getting posts' . $client->getErrorMessage());
}

$posts = $client->message->params[0];

$title_to_search_for = 'This is a duplicate title   ';

// loop through all of the $posts, see if the title is duped.
$title_to_search_for = trim(strtolower($title_to_search_for));

$is_duplicate = false;

foreach($posts as $post) {
    if (trim(strtolower($post->post_title) === $title_to_search_for)
        $is_duplicate = true;

    if (trim(strtolower($post->post_name) === $title_to_search_for)
        $is_duplicate = true;
}
```